# How to get the current location in watchOS 2?

Tags: objective-c, location, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I need to fetch the user current location for the WatchKit App in watchOS 2. How do I do this?

Comment: Why would this question be down voted?  It is a perfectly valid question.  smh

Answer (score 24):

The other answers are incorrect. You can request location directly on the watch for watch OS2. The available method is called `requestLocation`. It allows you to request a single location update.

E.g.

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface className : WKInterfaceController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

Then where you want to request location:

```
self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[self.locationManager requestLocation];
```

Then you will get a single callback in one of the following `CLLocationManagerDelegate` methods.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    // Callback here with single location if location succeeds
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // Error here if no location can be found
}
```

See the WWDC15 video "What's New in Core Location" - https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=714

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Thanks! But to it's important to mention that this not works in an ExtensionDelegate. In a "WKInterfaceController" it operates perfectly well.

Comment: @Blankarsch Is there any reason this is the case? What if we need a central manager independent of UI?