# CoreLocation not working on WatchKit 2.1

Tags: watchkit, core-location, watchos-2

The 2015 WWDC session 'What's New in Core Location' shows how to obtain the User's location on the watch. I followed the steps there and it didn't work. Went back to the session and noted that the speaker mentions a sample app: PotLoc. Downloaded built and ran that, also did not work. Then I thought maybe I needed to put it into a controller where I had a button and had to tap to start the process. Also failed.

The error is:

```
failed with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"
```

The code is pretty much the same as found in this ticket: [How to get the current location in watchOS 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669634/how-to-get-the-current-location-in-watchos-2/31682802#31682802).

I don't think it's a question of the authorization because the setting is in the info.plist for the application (not the watch app or extension) and the main app is doing CoreLocation lookups.

Any insight into what is failing appreciated (as the error message is utterly useless).