# iOS 11.3 , Watch OS 4.3 : Get user current location in watchOS 4.3?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, watchos-4

I have tried this in swift

[How to get the current location in watchOS 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669634/how-to-get-the-current-location-in-watchos-2)

But It's not working
Here is my code in WKInterfaceController

```
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)
    self.setupLocation()
}

extension InterfaceController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func setupLocation() {
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let currentLocation = locations.first else { return }
        self.currentLocation = currentLocation
        let location = "lat: \(self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)\nlong: \(self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
        self.locationLabel.setText(location)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("LOCATION MANAGER DID FAIL ERROR : \(error)")
    }
}
```

I have added permission in **WatchExtension** and **Main App** info.plist as well.

It's still not even asking permission alert.
What i'm missing ???? :(

Comment: I`m testing on simulator

Comment: Have you set Debug -> Location in the simulator?  That setting is needed for iOS.  I am not sure it is supported on watchOS simulator though.